# Is there a way of toggling dark mode using the Shortcuts app?

Tags: macos, applescript, automator, automation, shortcuts-app

I've come across ways (AppleScript to toggle dark mode with fading and How to toggle dark mode on and invert colors using Automator) of toggling dark mode using Automator and AppleScript, but haven't managed to do it using the new Shortcuts app. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Note that while editing a shortcut, you can use the search box to find actions (as illustrated in Gummibando's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Set Appearance → Turn appearance Dark

[image]

Invert works via either *Set Classic Invert* or *Set Smart Invert*

Comment: In addition to the above answer, note, you can create shortcuts to perform terminal commands too, however I think the darkmode command is a little bit complicated compared to other system commands.